# Java default values confusion, why none for function scoped variables?

Tags: java

I'm having some confusion with the reasoning behind what seems to me to be an inconsistency.

For example

```
public class Test
{
    static int a;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

So that will print out 0, as expected. But say we had  this instead,

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

This won't compile for me, complaining that a hasn't been initialized. I was expecting it to print out 0...

Which leads me to some questions:

1) Why don't function scoped variables have default values?

2) Could the static keyword be the reason? And why?

Comment: In Java only class variables have default values.  `Static` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java Language Specification explains the default [Initial values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is
>   initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10):
>
> For type byte, the default value is zero, that is, the value of
>   (byte)0.
>
> For type short, the default value is zero, that is, the value of
>   (short)0.
>
> For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
>
> For type long, the default value is zero, that is, 0L.
>
> For type float, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0f.
>
> For type double, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0d.
>
> For type char, the default value is the null character, that is,
>   '\u0000'.
>
> For type boolean, the default value is false.
>
> For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.

and also states

> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value
>   before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment
>   (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite
>   assignment (§16).

Both your questions can be answered by "Because the JLS says so".

A more complete answer would be the following:

A Class is a description of state and behavior. An object is the actual data. If you create an object, it must have definitive state, it cannot be in an uninitialized state.

Comment: Ah! I had read through the first part, but I didn't read the 14.4 and related docs. /embarrassed. Thanks!!
EDIT: Yea, I was hoping there was a more meaningful answer besides the 'it says so response', but I'm hearing this is more of the case in Java, (Python programmer here).

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Why don't function scoped variables have default values?

It is the rule defined by [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) that method variables are not initialized to thier default values. You need to initialize them beforeusing

> 2) Could the static keyword be the reason? And why?

Again form [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) rules, class instance variables are initialized to default values by the compiler. You may or may not initialize them.

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler never assigns default values to Local variables as mentioned in the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

You have to explicitly initialize them.